# Why does this url crash chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, https

If you enter this url:

https://demo.cmrg.net/

into a chrome browser it's crashing. Why is it so?

Answer (score 1):

This is a [regression](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=348987) that has a [patch](https://codereview.chromium.org/178003011/) in review.

Firefox reports this as `ssl_error_weak_server_ephemeral_dh_key`
[image: FF Error]